# joomla function call from external source

Tags: joomla

Assume there is a plugin in joomla named plug1, with file.php which contains class C1 and function callme(){requires using some joomla functionality}.

What is the easiest way to call this function from external source?

Comment: As @di3sel mentioned, i was trying to access using url requests. However all i get is error, therefore i was interested to hear how people deal with such issues. In addition my plugin directory contains subfolders. In one of the subfolders is my php file. Maybe this is the issue i fail

Comment: When you say "from an external source" what exactly do you mean. It is really hard to know what you are doing without some code and the specific error messages. You are saying you basically want to run a small Joomla application based on this plugin right? Have you considered just making a stand alone application instead (that does nothing but delivers what you want)?

Comment: To make it more clear - it is a webservice type request i want to simulate. A specific functionality implemented in joomla (user update, detail update) are performed in a plugin. Plugin is located in plugins/myplugin/sub/code.php. This code.php contains a class C and method M which i want to call from an external source, not in the page, but as a webservice.

Since functionality is implemented, making a stand alone app is possible, however use of standards in Joomla is preferable.

Comment: I think it is a lot easier to use a standalone for services, but if you really want to do this you need to provide a context for the plugin to run in. That is to say, you need to have a json document generated  ... basically a plugin is NOT the place to be doing such things, update belongs in a controller.  I would either make a simple JApplicationWeb that serves the JSON or make a simple component that only serves your JSON and has a model and a controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Joomla 3+, the best solution for that would be to use com_ajax. You can find more info about it here: http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

Your call should look like this:

```
index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=plug1&format=json
```

Params:
plugin - your plugin name without plg_
format - response format (if need to retrieve data from plugin)

Also you need method in your plugin called `onAjaxPlug1` (if plug1 is your plugin name).